# $page.props.user it works but $page.props.user.name doesn't work

Tags: laravel, vuejs3, inertiajs

I made an application using vue laravel and inertia, I'm trying to feed my application through the $page that inertia makes available, when I went to test in the console.log the $page.props.user works normally showing the array with all the data, but how much I try to call a property of the base, for example the name, I put $page.props.user.name it gives undefined, if you can help me thank you.

```js
mounted(){
  console.log(this.$page.props.user) 
  console.log(this.$page.props.user.name)
};
```

Controller:

```php
public function home(){
  $user = User::all();
  return Inertia::render('Home', [ 'user' => $user]);
}
```

Comment: whats the log output of `this.$page.props.user`?

Comment: Proxy {0: {…}}[[Handler]]: Object[[Target]]: Array(1)0: {id: 2, name: 'john snow', email: 'johnsnow@ctmac.gov.br', cpf/cnpj: '123564845211', função: 'Moto taxi', …}length: 1[[Prototype]]: Array(0)[[IsRevoked]]: false

Comment: @Flame do you know the reason?

Answer (score 1):

```php
$user = User::all();
```

This query returns all users **as an array** (a Laravel collection in fact). So the view will obviously receive an array as well.

You likely need `Auth::user()` (using the `Auth` facade) or whatever equivalent you have to retrieve the currently logged in user.

Comment: And in case I want to make a list of items how could I do it?

Comment: loop the array in javascript (and also name it "users" so you know it is an array) e.g. `for let user of this.$page.props.users { ... }`.